# What equipment do I need to listen to a synthesizer?

Tags: synthesizer

I was just given a used Arturia Mini Brute to mess around with. What basic equipment do I need to amplify/hear the sound produced? I have already purchased headphones. If it is not obvious, I have almost no experience with electronics.

Comment: Headphones are all you need. Is there something else you are trying to do where the headphones don't let you do that?

Comment: I do have headphones, but what about being able to listen/compose in an open space? I don't want to broadcast to a large audience, but maybe a small group...

Comment: Note that if you want to clarify your question, the way to do that is log on to the site and then click the grey "edit" button in the lower left corner of the question. Then you can change or add to your question and everyone will be able to see the changes and provide better answers.

Answer (score 3):

According to the "main features" information at the bottom of https://www.arturia.com/products/hardware-synths/minibrute/overview it has a 1/4" audio output, and a 1/4" headphone output.

Most "consumer quality" headphones have a smaller 3.5mm plug, which is the standard size on cellphones, etc. If that is what you have, you need a "3.5mm socket to 6.35mm jack plug audio stereo adaptor" like this (1/4 inch is the same size as 6.35mm).

[image]

These are very widely available, and cheap. As usual, you get what you pay for - the very cheapest ones may not be very durable.

Note, if you buy one by mail order, make sure you are ordering *exactly* what it says above - you don't want one has a 3.5mm *plug* and a 1.4" *socket*, which would let you plug "professional quality" headphones into a cellphone!

Comment: The cheapest aren't very durable, but in my experience even those tend to get lost before they stop working...

Answer (score 1):

Just plug in your headphones and let the fun begin.

Comment: Normally we like more involved answers here, and at the same time, it does seem like the asker already has what they need. This is normally a job for a comment to clarify what the asker is really talking about. We understand that you are not yet able to comment. As you can see, I have commented asking for more detail about the question. I think once we get more details, we will be able to answer with a complete, high quality answer. Right now, this answer has been flagged as being short and having little information. I'm not recommending deletion, but please be slower to answer in the future.