# Synthesizer question

Tags: synthesizer

Hi I asked a question the other day about my Mini-Brute synthesizer (gifted to me). Because i'm technically challenged, i have no idea just how to hook this up and what i need to do so to produce audible sounds...I have a set of headphones, but simply do not understand how to route this device thru speakers...Is it as simple as getting a 1/4" patch cord and hooking the units together? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you lose the password for your other account? If not, it would be better to log on with that account and edit your previous question. If you did lose the password, we can answer this question instead. In order to add more information to this question, please click the grey "edit" link in the lower left. We need some more information to help you. What speakers do you have? Do you have an amplifier? What kind of amplifier is it? Do you not have any speakers or amp and you need some help knowing what you options are for amplifying the synth?

Comment: The obvious first port of call has to be the user manual, available on line. It'll reveal an awful lot more, too.

Comment: For reference, here's the previous question: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/52621/what-equipment-do-i-need-to-listen-to-a-synthesizer